# Resources delete method not working with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, routes, crud

I am using devise gem for authentication. For the admin user I am trying to create a page where he will see the list of all users and will be able to delete them. Because devise does not provide action for delete I created a controller where I created destroy action.

controller:

```
  def destroy
    User.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "User destroyed."
    redirect_to("/devise")
  end
```

The view is simple, it just lists all users and posts a delete link next to them.

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <%= user.email %> <%= link_to 'Delete', :controller => :devise, :action => :destroy, :id => (user[:id]), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete this user permanently?" } %>
<% end %>
```

Up until this point it works - the page displays all users and the delete link too. However, when I try to delete random users it just opens them in new window instead of deleting them.

My routes are as follows:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :admins
  devise_for :users
  resources :devise
  resources :centres
  resources :users

  #match '/users/:id', :to => 'devise#show',    :as => :user,         :via => :get
  match '/users/:id', :to => 'devise#destroy', :as => :destroy_user, :via => :delete

  root 'welcome#index'
  get '/index', to: 'welcome#index' 
  get '/about', to: 'welcome#about' 
  get '/help', to: 'welcome#help'
end
```

I need to make the delete function work. Thank you.

Comment: Make sure that you're using `jquery` and `jquery_ujs`

Comment: could you be more specific, please?

Comment: Are these libraries loaded in your `application.js` ?

Comment: Does exist an controller for every route have in your `routes.rb`? It isn't also very common to use devise as name for the resource.

Comment: Yes, I have renamed now the controller's and resource's name from 'devise' to 'users'. I found that using controller named devise_controller.rb will mess everything up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution for the question I posted:

controlled:

```
  def destroy
    User.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "User destroyed."
    redirect_to("/users")
  end
```

view:

```
  <%= link_to "delete", user, method: :delete,
                                  data: { confirm: "Are you sure you want to permanently delete this user?" } %>
```

route:

```
  match '/users/:id', :to => 'users#destroy', :as => :destroy_user, :via => :delete
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, device doesn't handle destroy action. You should create a custom controller and provide a destroy action. In my case, i create a users_controller

users_controller:

```
def destroy
  @user.destroy

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to users_url }
    format.json { head :ok }
  end
end
```

html.erb:

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', user, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

routes.rb:

```
match '/users/:id', :to => 'users#destroy', :as => :destroy_user, :via => :delete
```

Comment: Thank you. This was useful however, it did not resolve my issue. But it did point me into the right direction. Below is the solution for my question.